# When does $\Vert AB \Vert = \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

### Motivation

If $a$ and $b$ are vector, then thinking simply vector 2 norm, $\Vert a \cdot b\Vert = \Vert b\Vert \Vert a\Vert \cos(a,b) $, we know the difference is simply a ratio between the angle of $a$ and $b$.

More generally, in a Hilbert space, Cauchy inequality holds so 
$$|\langle a,b\rangle|^2 \le \langle a,a\rangle\langle b,b\rangle$$
and we know the **only when a, b are parallel, the equality is achieved.**

### Question

Given two square matrix $A$ and $B$,
when does this happen?
$$\Vert AB \Vert = \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert$$

Let's simply assume matrix 2-norm, so $\Vert \cdot \Vert = \Vert \cdot \Vert_2$.

Comment: What is the 2-norm? The answer will change depending on the norm.

Comment: 2-norm is just matrix 2-norm or you can say it is an induced norm from the l2 normed vector space. It is the norm from operator sense, treating matrix as an operator.

Comment: It looks to me you have your definitions missmatched. Check again, you are around a solution, it looks like.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question! It saved me from a bad mistake in an answer, where I had written (unnecessarily) $\|BC\| = \|B\|\|C\|$, instead of $\|BC\| \leqslant \|B\|\|C\|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given $\Vert x \Vert =1$,  $$\Vert AB x \Vert \le \Vert A \Vert \Vert Bx \Vert,$$ the equality holds when $Bx$ hit on the direction of first right singular vector of $A$.

Then 
$$\Vert Bx \Vert \le \Vert B \Vert \Vert x \Vert$$  the equality holds when $x$ hit the first right singular vector of $B$.  However, now the $Bx$ aligned with first left singular vector of $B$ and it must match the first right singular vector of $A$.

Note that $$\Vert A B x\Vert \le \Vert A \Vert \Vert B\Vert \Vert x \Vert$$

When *both equality conditions are holds*, that is to say,

> the largest **left** singular vector of $B$ is parallel to the largest **right** singular vector of $A$

we have 
$$
\Vert A B\Vert  = \sup \Vert AB x\Vert/\Vert x \Vert = \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert 
$$

Comment: OP is using 2-norm. I think that _signifies_ $\|A\| = \left( \sum\limits_{p,q} A(p,q)^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$

Comment: Oh, you are OP.